# Cant make this calendar grid consistant accross browsers

Tags: php, css, html

I created a dynamically generated calendar that uses tables, an example of it can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/9bXEp/13/

I am having a lot of trouble making it render consistently across browser, it looks perfect in firefox but all out of alignment in chrome. If I alter the css to make it look fine in chrome is messes up firefox etc.

Can somebody take a look and advise on the css?

Also I am not sure if tables is the best way to do this? below is the code that actually generates it. The two files should run in your local host just link the style sheet to the main page.

Could this be done better with divs?

The glass that generates the grid:

```
class Gantt {

private $start_date;
private $end_date;
private $tasks;

public function __construct($start_date, $end_date, $tasks)
{
    $this->start_date = $start_date;
    $this->end_date = $end_date;
    $this->tasks = $tasks;
    //draw the grid
    $this->draw($this->start_date, $this->end_date, $this->tasks);
}

public function draw($start_date, $end_date, $tasks){

    $time_span = $this->year_month($start_date, $end_date);
    $day_count = $this->count_days($start_date, $end_date);
    $project_length = $this->time_range($start_date, $end_date);
    echo $project_length;

    echo '<table class="main_table"><tr>';

    echo '<td class="side_bar1"><div></div></td><td class="side_bar2"><div></div></td>';

    foreach($time_span as $year => $months) {

        echo '<td class=" main_table years" colspan="'.count($months).'">'.$year.'</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr><tr>';
    echo '<td class="side_bar1"><div></div></td><td class="side_bar2"><div></div></td>';

    foreach($time_span as $months) {

        foreach($months as $month => $days){
            echo '<td class="main_table years months">'.$month.'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    echo '<td><div></div></td><td class="side_bar2"><div></div></td>';
    $month_count = 0;//start month count
    foreach($time_span as $months) {
        $m=0;
        foreach($months as $days){

            echo '<td class="inner_container"><table class="main_table table_inner"><tr>';
            $i=0;
            foreach($days as $day => $d){
                if($i == 0){
                    echo '<td class="no-b"><div class="cell_width">'.$day.'</div></td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td class="inner_td"><div class="cell_width">'.$day.'</div></td>';
                }
                $i++;
            }
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
            $i=0;
            foreach($days as $d){
                if($d == 0){
                    echo '<td class="no-b2"><div class="cell_width">'.$d[0].'</div></td>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<td class="inner_td2"><div class="cell_width">'.$d[0].'</div></td>';
                }
                $i++;
            }
            echo '</tr></table></td>';
            $m++;
        }

        $month_count += $m; //total month count
    }

    foreach($tasks as $task){

        echo '</tr><tr><td class="task_bar1">'.$task.'</td><td class="task_bar2"></td><td class="no-b2" colspan="'.$month_count.'"><table class="main_table table_inner"><tr>';

        for ($x=0; $x< $day_count; $x++)
        {
            if($x==0){
                echo '<td class="no-b"><div class="cell_width day_block"></div></td>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<td class="inner_td"><div class="cell_width day_block"></div></td>';
            }

        }

        echo '</tr></table ></td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}


//Returns an array containing the years, months and days between two dates
public function year_month($start_date, $end_date)
{
    $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
    $end = new DateTime( $end_date);
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 month interval
    $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
    $aResult = array();

    foreach ( $period as $dt )
    {
        $aResult[$dt->format('Y')][$dt->format('F')][$dt->format('j')] = $dt->format('D');
    }

    return $aResult;
}

//Returns the total number of days between two dates
public function count_days($start_date, $end_date){

    $d1 = new DateTime($start_date);
    $d2 = new DateTime($end_date);
    $difference = $d1->diff($d2);
    return $difference->days;

}
//Returns the time span between two dates in years  months and days
public function time_range($start_date, $end_date){

    $datetime1 = new DateTime($start_date);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($end_date);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%y years %m months and %d days');
}

}
```

The css:

```
.main_table {
   border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   background-color: #F6F6F6;
   color: #484A4D;
   font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
   line-height: 24px;
   font-size:12px;
 }
.main_table th, td {
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 24px;
}
.years {
text-align:center;
font-size:13px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.inner_container {
border-left:0;
}
.table_inner {
border: 0;
table-layout: fixed;
}
.no-b {
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:0;
border-top:0;
border-left:0;
}
.no-b2 {
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
text-align:center;
border-bottom:0;
}

.inner_td {
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
border-bottom:0;
border-top:0;

}
.inner_td2 {
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
border-bottom:0;
}
.cell_width{
width: 25px;
height:23px;
}
.side_bar1 div {
width:110px;
}
ar2 div {
width:120px;

}
.side_bar2 {
border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.task_bar1, .task_bar2 {
border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
padding-left:5px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.day_block {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

.inner_container:last-child .no-b2:last-child {
border-right:0;
}
.inner_container .table_inner .inner_td:last-child {
border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
 }
.inner_container:last-child .inner_td:last-child {
border-right:0;
}
.table_inner .inner_td:last-child {
border-right:0;
}
```

The main file

```
 include('gantt.php');

 $tasks[0] = 'task1';
 $tasks[1] = 'task2';
 $tasks[3] = 'task3';

$gantt1 = new Gantt('2007-03-24', '2007-06-26', $tasks);
```

Comment: i just opened it in safari 6.1 and FF 28,  both looks the same to me...

Comment: do they look fine or is the grid a bit lumpy?